# VB.Net XElement: specific attribute from combobox looping through XML

Tags: vb.net, xelement

I want the value of a specific attribute (e.g. title_1 in my html example) which I select with a combobox in visual studio. I have a problem with my looping through the attributes. It works only with title_1 and stops after the title_1.

Following my html-file

```html
<div id="main">
 <div id="title_1">
  <p>product name</p>
 </div>
 <div id="title_2">
  <p>product highlights</p>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <p>product price - product size - product date</p>
 </div>
</div id="main">
```

As a result, if I selcet **title_2** in the ComboBox1 I want **product highlights** in my TextBox1. If I select content in the ComboBox1 I want **product price - product size - product date** in my TextBox1. Until now it works only with title_1, here I got **product name** in my TextBox1

Here my code

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("myPATH\file.html")
     Dim attributes As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("div")

     For Each item As XElement In attributes
        If attributes.@id = ComboBox1.Text Then
            TextBox1.Text = attributes.Value
        End If
     Next
   End Sub
End Class

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just a typo. You iterate each `item` in `attributes`, but then you don't access `item`, rather `attributes`.

```vb
For Each item As XElement In attributes
   If attributes.@id = ComboBox1.Text Then
       TextBox1.Text = attributes.Value
   End If
Next
```

Change it to this

```vb
For Each item As XElement In attributes
    If item.@id = ComboBox1.Text Then
        TextBox1.Text = item.Value
    End If
Next
```

Fixed.

Also, your html included an attribute in the closing tag. Is that valid? I had to remove it to make the code work.

```html
</div id="main">
```

I would add this line to clear TextBox1 prior to matching the value, in case there is no match

```vb
TextBox1.Clear()
```

You probably load the attributes into the ComboBox. But if you don't, use this. It would make the question more complete if you included it

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim xelement As XElement = XElement.Load("myPATH\file.html")
    Dim attributes As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Descendants("div")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = attributes.Select(Function(a) a.@id).ToList()
End Sub
```